# findViewById error on appwidgetprovider

Tags: java, android

It doesn't show the text from internet, just shows 000.

I wanted to get a text from internet and show on widget.

But I haven't got it to work successfully.

This is the code (Java class):

```
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class simple_widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public void onCreateView(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            // Create a URL for the desired page
            URL url = new URL("mysite.com/thefile.txt");

            // Read all the text returned by the server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.activity_simple_widget);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, str);

            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you add error that you are getting?

Comment: Yeah, cannot resolve method findViewById @VladimirJovanović

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify it using RemoteViews. You can't actually modify a view on the appwidget directly

[Here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.widget.RemoteViews) are a few examples

Comment: Thank you, I changed it and doesn't have now error but it doesn't show the text from internet. @Rafa

Comment: That could be for various reasons. Check what response you are getting when you are hitting the endpoint. But the original problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to use setText() in appWidgetProvider class. But this class does not allow findViewById(). You need to use a function of RemoteView Class for this purpose.

[CharSequence Method | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setCharSequence(int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

in your case:

```
remoteViews.setCharSequence(R.id.textView,"setText",str);
```

it works for EditText,TextView,TextClock.
You can replace `String MethodName` with the name of method like getText,setText,setTimeZone etc.

For Buttons RemoteViews offer the following function

[setOnClickResponse | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setOnClickResponse(int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews.RemoteResponse))

this is the equivalent of

> View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Similarly a lot of other methods are available now such as `setFloat()`, `setLong()` which work same as `setCharSequence()`.

you can choose between them based on the datatype of parameters you want to pass.

here is the link to understand and view the list of all RemoteView functions

[RemoteViews | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews)

Hope this helps